# Передача переменных в HTML шаблон через Django

Tags: python, html, django

Имеется такой Django код:

```
def index(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tempstring = request.POST.get('title')
        form = HashForm(request.POST)  #
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            error = 'Wrong link!'

    form = HashForm()
    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error,
    }
    return render(request, 'hash/index.html', data)
```

И такой HTML код:

```
{% extends 'hash/base.html' %}

{% block title%}
Linkslayer - Main Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
<h1>Main page</h1>
<div class="features">
    <p class="fw-lighter">Paste the link in the input window below to shorten it</p>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }}<br>
        
        <span>{{ error }}</span>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Convert</button><br><br>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Имеется ли возможность сделать так, чтобы между `{{ form.title }}<br>` и `<span>{{ error }}</span>` выводилась переменная `tempstring` из Django кода? И если это возможно (или нет), то как это реализовать?

Comment: Добавьте её в контекст `data` и выводите на здоровье через `{{ tempstring }}`

Comment: Пробовал, никак. Может быть я что-то не так делаю?
`data = { 'form': form, 'error': error, 'tempstring': tempstring }` и в HTML `{{ tempstring }}`.
В итоге получаю `NameError at /home/
name 'tempstring' is not defined`

Comment: Добавьте саму форму в вопрос.

Comment: Не понял, можно подробнее?